# Vue router refreshing page instead of navigating to it. What is the difference between these 2 code examples?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to click a "checkout" button that sends cart data to a backend and redirects me to an url the backend produces.

My code isn't working. It's giving me a valid url, but when I try to redirect to that url the page just refreshes and I don't get redirected anywhere.

I have a working version of the code, I tried to just copy paste it from another project but it didnt work. I tried to refactor it to work with my code, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

---

The top code is the **working** code, the code below it is my **not working** code. Can someone help me understand the difference? What is going wrong with my code? What is the difference between my code and the working code? How do I make it function like the working code?

**Working**

-**Frontend**

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onBeforeMount } from "vue";
import CheckoutSummary from "../components/CheckoutSummary.vue";
import CheckoutButton from "../components/CheckoutButton.vue";

// Reactive data
const isLoading = ref(false);
const cart = ref([]);

// Get the cart data
onBeforeMount(async () => {
  const response = await fetch("/api/shopping-cart").then((r) => r.json());
  cart.value = response.cart;
});

// Click handler for button
const redirectToStripe = async () => {
  isLoading.value = true;

  const response = await fetch("/api/create-checkout-session", {
    method: "POST",
  });
  const { url } = await response.json();

  window.location.href = url;
};
</script>
```

-**Backend**

```
// Create a Checkout Session
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  // Make an array of just our Stripe Price ID and quantities
  const lineItems = USER_SHOPPING_CART.map((item) => {
    return {
      price: item.stripePriceId,
      quantity: item.quantity,
    };
  });

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    mode: "payment",
    line_items: lineItems,
    success_url: `http://localhost:3000/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `http://localhost:3000/`,
  });
  return res.send({ url: session.url });
});
```

**Not Working**

-**Frontend**

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

const router = useRouter();

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars, no-undef
const props = defineProps({
  isLoading: Boolean,
});

const store = useStore();
const cartItems = computed(() => store.getters.getCheckout);

const redirectToStripe = async () => {
  const { url } = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(cartItems.value),
  }).then((response) => response.json());

  console.log("url=", url);
  router.go(url);
};
</script>
```

-**Backend**

```
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  // Make an array of just our Stripe Price ID and quantities
  const lineItems = req.body.map((item) => {
    console.log("lineItems= ", item.item.priceId, item.item.quantity);
    return {
      price: item.item.priceId,
      quantity: item.item.quantity,
    };
  });

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    mode: "payment",
    line_items: lineItems,
    success_url: `http://localhost:8080/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `http://localhost:8080/`,
  });
  return res.send({ url: session.url });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `router.push(url)` instead of `router.go(url)`

when using vue router its a good practice to use router.push to navigate instead of location.href because the later may produce some unexpected behavior.

Comment: This directs me to: `http://localhost:8080/https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1Yd93NLtiw37dw921fO`..............................instead of `https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1Yd93NLtiw37dw921fO`........anyway to fix that?

Comment: i don't know if it's possible to redirect to an external url with vue router.
in this case use location.href

Answer (score 0):

[`router.go`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/Router.html#go) is a method to be used when you want to move 'x' number of pages forward of backward in your browsing history.

[`router.push`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location) is to navigate to a page by adding a new item in the browser history. But it is meant for pages inside your application. Ex - going from '/about' page to '/careers' page on the same website. That is why we give the relative path or a page name to the `push` method.

From what I can see you are trying to redirect to a completely different page. In that case you should use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to open the page.

If it is a link to a checkout page then it might be better to open in a new tab using `window.open(url, '_blank')`